# Bookmarklets not loading properly on FB

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using this to load my bookmarklets on a secure web page.

```
javascript:(function() {
      document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = 'http://mydoamin/bookmarklet/pets.js?' + Math.random();
})();
```

I want to know if there is other way to load bookmarklets on a secure web page.

**AFTER SEARCHING**

I found this and it works :)

```
 javascript:var s=document.getElementById('script');
 if(s){
     s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
 }    
 s=document.createElement('script');
 s.setAttribute('src', 'http://mydoamin/bookmarklet/pets.js');
 s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
 s.setAttribute('id', 'script');
 document.body.appendChild(s);
 void(0);
```

Any one still want to correct it please go for it.

Comment: what do you mean by `properly` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an element first, before you can adjust the properties, and aside from that you have a bracket error, the second bracket after createElement('script') should be removed and placed at the end of the line. Try this code:

```
   javascript:(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.src="http://mydoamin/bookmarklet/pets.js?"+Math.random();document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(a);}());
```